# How to write SQL Subquery queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a database which has 5 table

COURSES (***CourseID***, CourseName, Credit) // CourseID is primary key

TEACHERS (***SSN***, Name)  // SSN is primary key

OFFER (***CourseID***, ***SSN***)  // CourseID and SSN are foreign key

STUDENTS (***StudentID***, Name, Department)  // StudentID is primary key

ENROLL (***StudentID***, ***CourseID***, ***Semester***)

And i want to find the names of the students who enroll to courses that are enrolled by student whose name is “Jack Lion”.

I tried the below statements but i can't figure out how to solve.

```
SELECT STUDENTS.Name from STUDENTS
WHERE STUDENTS.StudentID IN (SELECT ENROLL.StudentID from ENROLL
 -- I don't know what to write here
)
```

I just got this far can u help me or at least give me some examples that would help me to solve this. I use Microsoft sql server by the way.

Comment: Is it a course requirement that you  have to use a sub query? And do they have to enroll to all the course that jack has enrolled for?

Comment: Why did you tag other databases if you're using sql server?

Comment: @Shawn Because i thought it is not that different from each other mssql and mysql etc.

Comment: @byakuyaxx2  'not that different from each other' - not the case and the answers could be very different - as they could be for sqlserver depending on which version you are on..PS which version are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes you are right. I use MSSQL server management studio 18. But I have to use SQL-99 Standarts to solve this problem.

Comment: One last question  do you mean in the same semester?

Comment: No, It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your subqueries

```
SELECT STUDENTS.Name from STUDENTS
WHERE STUDENTS.StudentID IN (SELECT ENROLL.StudentID 
                            from ENROLL
                             WHERE CourseID IN (SELECT CourseID 
                                                FROM ENROLL 
                                                WHERE StudentID IN (SELECT StudentID 
                                                                    FROM  STUDENTS  
                                                                    WHERE Name = 'Jack Lion'


                                             )
                                          )
                        )
```

Comment: @byakuyaxx2 how does this work? You sauy in a comment: *they have to enroll all the courses that jack has enrolled*

Comment: I saw that and it was my fault i gave you the wrong information. I checked the problem and it doesn't say they have to enroll all the courses. Sorry for that.